# Code Runs Even When New Row was not Added to Table - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

My code is supposed to be a simple table length check.
If the table length increases, a macro runs.
Unfortunately, it runs when I modify any data in an existing record. **But it only happens once!**
It occurs when I open the workbook initially and then try to modify anything in the workbook. After which, it runs as it should, only when you added a new entry.
Sub is located on the worksheet that contains static cell `A1`. This is the problem macro. It seems to behave as if there is a difference between the number of rows and the static range. But again, only when you initially open the workbook!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()


    Dim n As Long

    n = GetTableSize()
    If n > LastRowNumber Then NewDatabaseEntry
    ' Always set LastRowNumber so that even after entries are deleted (n < NumRows),
    ' adding new entries will work correctly.
    LastRowNumber = n

End Sub
```

Supporting macro in a separate module:

```
Option Explicit

Public LastRowNumber As Long
'This will be used to monitor the number of rows in the
'Projects worksheet. This will then be compared to the
'Value of the formula in the TableSize worksheet.
'The value in TableSize will have a variable 'n'.
Public Function GetTableSize() As Long

  GetTableSize = Worksheets("TableSize").Range("A1").Value2
End Function
```

This sub is located on the worksheet where the table being monitored resides:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

  LastRowNumber = GetTableSize()
End Sub
```

`NewDatabaseEntry` is the module that alerted me to the fact that there was a problem as it shows a pop-up before it runs. Otherwise, I would've been unaware of there being a problem in the first place.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's on Range("A1")? A formula?

Comment: Why `Value2`? Is there some purpose?

Comment: Value2 is just faster, isn't it? I use it as default unless I'm pulling dates.

Comment: There's a couple of issues with this method - LastRowNumber is set from A1 value but if there's an error running code it'll set to 0 - also, what's updating the value in cell A1? If it's not updating properly then it might just go round in a circle and n will never = less than LastRowNumber - may I suggest using a `.cells(.rows.count, 1).end(xlup).row` style line in code to get a last row rather than a static cell in A1 maybe?

Comment: @RicardoA `=ROW(INDEX(Records,1,1))+ROWS(Records)-1`.     'Records' being my table.

Comment: Now that you have your question answered you can also use ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Records").ListRows.Count to get the total Rows on the Table instead of a formula

Comment: @RicardoA I changed my code to `GetTableSize = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Records").ListRows.Count` and got a subscript out of range error. Am I implementing your suggestion wrong?

Comment: Change "Sheet1" to the name of the Sheet where the Table is located.

Comment: @RicardoA My code doesn't work anymore, as in, it does nothing when I add a new line. I would have to add more code somewhere else as this is not a simple replacement of one line like I thought it would be.

Comment: That is very strange, i get the total rows from my table with just that line. I am in excel 2013 i am not sure if this changes for your version. I guess the formula will have to do for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Workbook_Open` sub is in a sheet module, then it's not being called when the workbook opens. Your `LastRowNumber` variable is defaulting to a value of zero - `0`. Then, when you make any change to the data, since `n > 0`, it calls `NewDatabaseEntry`. After the first time, the `LastRowNumber` variable has the value it's supposed to have, and everything works as expected (if I understood your explanation correctly).

Instead, the `Workbook_Open` sub needs to be in the workbook module -  `ThisWorkbook`. Event-code has to be in it's expected location to be called correctly.

---

*(I almost added this as a comment, then realized this is probably what's causing the issue...)*

Comment: Crying tear of joy. I had this issue for over a month and just did not see that it said `Workbook_Open` on that module. Moved it into `ThisWorkbook` Excel Object and problem solved! Thank you.